# Method returns nothing

Tags: c#

I'm really stuck with this one. I have a method that should return a list of strings.

```
public List<string> getValueFromAttributeName(string strXMLPath, string strXMLNode, string strAttributeName, string strAttributeValue)
{
    // initialite the return list
    List<string> lstValues = new List<string>();

    // create XML object
    XmlDocument targetXML = new XmlDocument();
    // load domain config into XML object
    targetXML.Load(strXMLPath);
    // get the root node of the XML object
    XmlElement targetXMLRoot = targetXML.DocumentElement;
    // get target XML parent node
    XmlNode targetXMLElement = targetXMLRoot.SelectSingleNode(strXMLNode);
    // process each child node
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in targetXMLElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        // if the child node's specified attribute value is equal to desired value add to list
        if (childNode.Attributes[strAttributeName] != null && childNode.Attributes[strAttributeName].Value.ToLower() == strAttributeValue.ToLower())
        {
            lstValues.Add(childNode.InnerText);
        }
    }
    return lstValues;

}
```

When debugging this method, i have the List lstValues filled with one value ("true").

So, when calling that method from another, the list is EMPTY?!

```
List<string> lstSettings = new List<string>();
lstSettings = getValueFromAttributeName(strConfigFile, "/config/settings", "name", "someSetting");
```

Comment: Maybe you have no values in your xml? Show us your xml and we can probably tell you what's the problem

Comment: Sry, edited the questions some seconds ago. I have values in that xml, and when debugging the method, the lstValues has one entry...

Comment: When debugging you have values in `lstValues`, but then after you return the result is empty? It sounds like a debugging issue, since that's impossible. Note that if you set a breakpoint on `lstSettings =...`, you'll see an empty list - you need to move past that line.

Comment: Well, I know how to debug, thanks for that hint...

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that lists are reference types in C# (you assign an empty list to lstSettings before overwriting that reference with the one return from your method) Maybe the passing of your result to the second method is using the empty list?

Comment: Can you post the XML? There could be an error there.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a bug (?) in Visual Studio. Calling the method, the list is empty, but when I do something with the list, e.g. `lstSettings.Select(x => x.ToLower());', Visual Studio says the List has values (the expected). This is strange, because I've done it this way 1000 times before... thanks, anyway.

Comment: @TheFunkyAlex What do you think is more likely: That your code is buggy, or that you discovered a highly visible bug in a piece of software used daily by millions of people?